# Is there any relation between Kolasura killed by Devi and Kola-viddhangshi mentioned in Devi Mahatmya?

Tags: puranas, devi

Is there any relation between Kolasura who was killed killed by Devi and the 'Kola-viddhangshi' group mentioned in the Devi Mahatmya?

Answer (score 1):

No, Kolasura has no link to Kolavidhwamsis.

Kolasura was the asura slayed by Bhagwati Mookambika.
Whereas, Kolavidhwamsi was the sect amongst Kshtriyas who attacked & defeated Kola clan.

Kolas are the tribes of abnormal origins. And, are barbarians, could be considered as outcastes. They inhabitted the hilly regions of Central Plateau regions.

I don't have much shastra pramana for this, but Makandey Purana mentiones this in one of the chapters on geography,

> the Kolas, those who inhabit Carmapaṭṭa
> (Carmapatta regions lies near Bundelkhand & Chotta Nagpur Plateau)

Kola tribe still survives, read [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kol_people#:%7E:text=The%20Kol%20people%20are%20a,India%20around%20five%20centuries%20ago.)

Even wikipedia agrees to this, that they lived earlier in hilly regions of Chotta Nagpur.

Thus, it is evident that duo are spread apart with no link in them.

Also, one can ask that the Devi Mahatmya dates back to the 2nd Swairochish Manvantara, while I mentioned that Kola clan is still thriving in 7th Manvantar.                How can that be possible?
The answer is, in every Kalpa & Manvantara the same ancedotes appear, although just with a few changes in events.

**कालिकार्पणमास्तु ।**